# Docker error with pipenv on django app: Warning: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile

Tags: django, docker, pipenv

When I was trying to dockerize my django app, I followed a tutorial telling me to structure my Dockerfile like this

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code/

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system

EXPOSE 8000
```

After I saved that and run `docker build .`

the system threw me this error

```
Warning: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile 
installation,not installation of specific packages. Aborting.
```

I think it is complaining about the `--system` suffix above but the tutorial says it's crucial to have it so that my packages are applied in the entire docker container. I'm new to docker and even pipenv because I took over a previous person's code and isn't sure where their pipfile is or even if they have a pipfile. If you have any insights on how to fix this error thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there `Pipfile` in your project dir?

Comment: No i don't think there is, is that what's causing the issue? I think the previous person was not using pipenv , should I create one?

Comment: Yes, your warning is saying you just that. `--system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile`. So before running `docker build .` run `pipenv install` in your project folder

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Thank you!

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev You should consider adding an answer and explaining it. It was really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @AnkitPopli made an answer

Answer (score 17):

```
pipenv --rm
```

This helped me! I was starting the "Django for beginners" and at the very beginning, got this error (accidently deleted Pipfile & Pipfile.lock)

Answer (score 6):

Your warning is saying you that there is no `Pipfile` in your project dir.

> --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile.

So before running

```
docker build .
```

run

```
pipenv install
```

in your project folder

Comment: i can see one benefit of this - the build fails if the Pipfile.lock is outdated. which is awesome IMO

Comment: @AnkitPopli actually it shouldn't fail if Pipfile.lock is outdated. I would suggest using `--keep-outdated` flag.

Comment: For me it fails in docker and the Pipfile exists in the current directory. This doesn't seem to be correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### It has Error in pipenv

It is 
 `ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.`

#### try it

`pipenv check` or `python3 -m pipenv check`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using Docker bind mounts!

**Summary**: In my case, I was using bind mounts in my dev environment, and [mounting a docker bind mount on a non-empty directory](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container) would overwrite the contents of the container's directory, removing the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, which showed the error mentioned when running the container.

### Explanation

##### Directory structure on the host

```
> ls project/
docker-compose.yml Dockerfile Pipfile Pipfile.lock app/
```

##### Dockerfile

My `Dockerfile` would copy the contents of the project and then install the dependencies with `pipenv`, like this:

```
FROM python:3.8
# ...
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/
RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile
COPY ./app /app/
CMD ["pipenv", "run", "uvicorn", "etc..", "--reload"]
```

`Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock` and the code of `./app` would all be in the same `/app` directory inside the container.

##### docker-compose.yml

I wanted uvicorn to hot-reload, so I mounted the code in `/app` inside the container's `/app` directory.

```
service:
 app:
   #...
   volumes:
   - type: bind
     source: ./app
     target: /app
```

This meant that when I changed the code in `/app`, the code in the container's `/app` directory would also change.

##### Effects

The side effect of this bind mount is that the content mounted on `/app` "obscured" the content previously copied in there.

*Container's content with the bind mount:*

```
> ls app/
code1.py code2.py
```

*Container's content without the bind mount:*

```
> ls app/
Pipfile Pipfile.lock code1.py code2.py
```

##### Solution

Either make sure that you include the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` as well when mounting the bind mount, or make sure that you `COPY` these 2 files to a directory that won't get overwritten by a bind mount.